# Erratic outputs from a second order system when input is too small

Tags: control, mems

I'm modeling a simple Mass-Spring-Damper system to represent the torsional behavior of a micromirror. With references to some papers ([this one](http://www.webphysics.altervista.org/nanotech/dida/cad/micromirror.pdf) mainly), I've constructed the model of a torsional mass spring damper system.

Governing equation:

$$m\dfrac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} + c \dfrac{d \theta}{dt} + k~\theta = T$$

Where T = Torque.

Calculated values (micromirror):

m = 3.61*10^-4 kg*um^2

c = 4.62*10^-3 uN*um*s

k = 1.03 uN*um

[image: Simulink Model]

The main issue I've been having is that below a certain input torque (~10^-6), my output seems to become unstable. I have shown examples of the good case (input is large enough), and the bad case (input is too small).

Input = ~10^-5
[image: Good]
Input = ~10^-9
[image]

I'm stumped - I've been looking at this for a while without any solid grasp as to what is causing this to happen. I can increase the input by as much as I want and I will still see stable behavior, it is only at low input that this occurs. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or neglecting?

Comment: I know nothing about MEMS design, but as a computer engineer I'm inclined to guess: quantization noise and rounding error in your computations.

Comment: @PhilFrost Hmm, I'm unfamiliar with the concept - how does it apply here?

Comment: A computer with finite memory can only represent so many numbers. When you start dealing with smaller numbers, then the difference between two adjacent numbers becomes more significant. Even floating point numbers have a limit to how small they can get. Maybe the noise of rounding to the nearest representable number is introducing significant noise, or maybe you are bumping up against the smallest representable number in some step of the calculation. "Clipping", or excessively poor SNR, to make analogies.

Comment: Again, just a guess. Most of your question is over my head. It might also be interesting to try with even smaller inputs to see if the problem holds. Some ways of representing numbers have significant discontinuities in precision at some points, and maybe that's introducing some non-linear response into your calculations; perhaps by going even smaller you will get out of the problematic range.

Comment: @PhilFrost Ah okay, thanks for the summary. I found that when I took a simple example (I believe it had something like m = 1, c = 0.5, b = 2), and gave that an incredibly small input (even smaller than I try with my model), it still gave the output shape I was expecting. So that leads me to believe it isn't a problem with the magnitude, but with my model. I also tried with an even smaller input to my model, and it gave the same shape but the peaks were greater relative to the rest of the signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fiddling with (reducing) the tolerance settings on the solver.

[image]

It's just a differential equation solver with a graphic front end, much like SPICE, for the EEs here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll play around with it. Do you have any suggestions for which of these parameters I should start with?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using op-amps or integrating and summing with algorithms? I have done this many times with op-amps, both forced and unforced harmonic oscillators.

If algorithmic, how are numbers represented? Full floating point? Fixed point? What is your method of integration? Newton-Feynman (with half step initialization) is simple and very good but there are some conditions that cause instability, though I would expect them to go off to infinity. Fourth order Runge-Kutta is pretty solid (add a predictor-corrector and it is great). However, in any of these you may need to scale to avoid numerical problems with round off and the common problem of multiplying a very large FP number by a very small one.

Can you describe the setup?

Comment: I'm using information flow modeling in Simulink (implementing integrating and summing with blocks, the model is in my post above). I don't have any particular algorithms as far as I know? Once I complete the block diagram and set the constants, I run the simulation within Simulink. I'll give you a link to the simulation and integration setup shortly

Comment: [Simulation setup](http://i.imgur.com/rCSUrRv.png) and [integration settings](http://i.imgur.com/NrIRlFu.png)

Comment: I see it in the PDF. The 1/s in the inegrators is funny to me. Does Simulink use Laplace Transforms?  Anyway, it uses some kind of numerical integration or transform. Is the only difference between yours and the PDF paper the physical parameters?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how it does it to be honest. For the mechanical model, yes - the physical constants vary. When I'm above 10^-5 as an input, I get the same result as in the paper, its only lower that my solution seems to deteriorate

Comment: Sorry I don't know about Simulink. But you are probably onto something with the magnitude. Your example of bad out put is after all 4 orders of magnitude lower than the good one. Without knowing an exact answer, I would just scale and problem to fit in the area where you know it works. You can scale frequency and everything. I bet you can do the same thing with Mathematica and not get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scale of the input numbers and the two images, it's likely that what you see is just numerical limitations, not model related. With floating point numbers subtraction, for example, is unstable for small differences and chaotic and limit cycle behavior can result. If you look at the first plot at the same scale as the second you will probably find the same kind of noise where not much should be going on.

You might change units from MKS to Gaussian (CGS). That would increase the magnitude of numbers. For example changing Newton-meters to dyne-centimeters would increase compliance (k) by a factor of \$10^8\$.